# Example to save and load a sub graph in TensorFlow?

Tags: serialization, tensorflow

I created a model within a variable/name scope and would like to store its graph definition and variables to disk to later load it without defining the graph again. How can I save and load all operations and variables within a given variable/name scope?

Conveniently, I would like to just use [`tf.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver). Its `save()` has an option to store the meta graph but `restore()` does not seem to import it. Moreover, in the saver constructor, I can specify a list of parameters, but not a name scope to control what operations are saved.

There is also [`tf.train.write_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#write_graph) but I couldn't find an explanation of what it is and how it relates to the saver class and meta graph.